# JavaScript AWS Cognito Connection Problems "NetworkError"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm running into a strange problem with AWS Cognito. I'm able to create user accounts, however when I attempt to set the created user to a group it is
giving me a network timed out error.

Setup:

```
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  region: 'us-east-1 ', // 100% sure this is the correct region
  apiVersion: '2016-04-18'
})

const UserPoolId = config.cognito.userPoolId
const ClientId = config.cognito.clientId
const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool({ UserPoolId, ClientId })
```

Creating account:

```
userPool.signUp(email, password, [ emailAttribute ], null, (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err)
      return res.redirect('/signup')
    }

    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminAddUserToGroup({
      GroupName: 'TRIAL',
      UserPoolId,
      Username: email
    }, (err, data) => {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err)
        return res.redirect('/signup')
      }

      res.redirect('/dashboard')
    })
  })
```

The account gets made correctly, however when attempting to add the new account to a group I get this error:

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.239.207.44:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
  message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT 104.239.207.44:443',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '104.239.207.44',
  port: 443,
  region: 'us-east-1 ',
  hostname: 'cognito-idp.us-east-1',
  retryable: true,
  time: 2018-06-20T14:01:49.029Z }
```

I find this very strange as I just was able to create an account successfully.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you are not connected to any VPN.

Comment: Still any one getting this issue. @Hawk yes I am using the vpn to connect cognito. and facing the same problem.